# SQL - Subquery returned more than 1 value when using IF

Tags: sql, if-statement

```
declare @i int
if (select username from q3) = 'wendy'
begin
    set @i = 1
    print cast(@i as varchar)
end
```

When I execute the code above I get an error saying

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery 
follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Can someone please help me fix this? I know what it means but I don't really know how to fix it. I've tried searching for a solution but I can't seem to find anything related to my problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? (Describe the whole scenario.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select username from q3` returns more rows than 1. Consider changing your `IF` to `IF EXISTS` like below:

```
declare @i int
if EXISTS (select username from q3 WHERE username = 'wendy')
begin
    set @i = 1
    print cast(@i as varchar)
end
```

or to `IN` like below:

```
declare @i int
if 'wendy' IN (select username from q3)
begin
    set @i = 1
    print cast(@i as varchar)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to execute only if there is an user called wendy you can try with this:

```
DECLARE @i int
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM q3 WHERE username  = 'wendy')
BEGIN
   SET @i = 1
   PRINT CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)
END
```

Comment: Will execute, but I'm not sure if in the way as OP expects.